pipenv return odd error when installing packages
I am new to python. Have multiple versions of python installed on my mac. When trying to use pipenv to manage dependencies for a legacy project (3.6 <= python <3.8). I ran
/Users/user/.pyenv/shims/pipenv --python /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.16/bin/python install --dev

and here is what I got
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (166d15)...
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: Traceback (most recent call last):
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/__pip-runner__.py", line 50, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: runpy.run_module("pip", run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.16/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.16/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.16/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: exec(code, run_globals)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/__main__.py", line 28, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: spec.loader.exec_module(pipenv)
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from pipenv.cli import cli # noqa
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/cli/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from .command import cli # noqa
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 4, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from pipenv import environments
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/environments.py", line 9, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from pipenv.utils.shell import env_to_bool, is_env_truthy, isatty
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/utils/shell.py", line 16, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from pipenv.vendor.pythonfinder.utils import ensure_path, parse_python_version
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pythonfinder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from .models import SystemPath
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pythonfinder/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from .path import SystemPath
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: File "/Users/user/Library/Python/3.9/lib/python/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/pythonfinder/models/path.py", line 10, in <module>
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: from functools import cached_property
[pipenv.exceptions.InstallError]: ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property' from 'functools' (/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.16/lib/python3.7/functools.py)
ERROR: Couldn't install package: {}
Package installation failed...
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:1052: ResourceWarning: subprocess 65854 is still running

it switched to the version of system python (3.9) in the middle. And I have no clue of the "subprocess ... is still running". Have been puzzled by this for weeks. Can I have help to fix this please?

I'm experiencing something similar. I'm using pyenv to install different versions, and now pipenv has a similar failure.

This isn't going to be a great answer, but my error was similar. It started when I changed what version of python was called out in the Pipfile. I had just installed a new version with pyenv.
I used pipenv --rm to remove the virtualenv for that project.
Then I tried running other commands and they started working correctly again. My guess is something in the virtualenv was trying to use the wrong python.
